# How to pass computer sound output to Skype without cables and air?

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, sharing

My foreign language teacher wants to play digital sound over Skype session. Is it possinble to redirect some program output to Skype without air or cables?

Comment: Virtual cables, stereo mix for Realtek devices or just share the screen would be good for me. Did you try any of those?

Comment: Just try to Google it, there're several suggestions, like this: https://itstillworks.com/play-sounds-over-skype-having-put-mic-up-speaker-22542.html

Comment: @Dims are you want solution for windows 10...or some other OS

Comment: @K7AAY hearing on transmit end is not a requirement, so go on

Comment: @Androidquery Windows 10 please

Answer (score 3):

**There are many ways**

1. Windows (audio properties Seetings)
2. Realtek or Sound card devices mixers
3. Virtual Cables Softwares
4. Many  Softwarers

**According to website itstillworks.com link given below says**

https://itstillworks.com/play-sounds-over-skype-having-put-mic-up-speaker-22542.html

> 1. Right-click the “Speakers” icon on your Windows taskbar. Select “Recording Devices.”
> 2. Right click an empty space on the “Select a recording device” pane and click “Show Disabled Devices.” You will see a new device titled “Stereo Mix.” Right-click this and select “Enable.”
> 3. Click “OK” to close the “Recording Devices” pane. Open Skype.
> 4. Click “Tools” and select “Options” in the Skype application.
> 5. Click the “Audio Settings tab.” Click the drop-down next to “Microphone” and select “Stereo Mix” from the available options. Click “Save” to apply the changes. Once saved, all audio on your computer, including that of your microphone and open applications, will be audible to anyone you're communicating with via Skype.

**see the videos and links for  further options**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZTNffLCUs4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UMNQhjlmLw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-sW6XcCyhY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsQSif-kjJA

https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/record-sound-using-line-in-microphone-windows/

https://www.howtogeek.com/364369/how-to-record-your-pc%E2%80%99s-audio-with-virtual-audio-cable/

[Set output audio of windows as input audio of microphone](https://superuser.com/questions/1133750/set-output-audio-of-windows-as-input-audio-of-microphone)