# How can I take control of the input stream of a (virtual) audio device in windows?

Tags: windows-10, microphone, audio-recording

My wish is to send my audio into the microphone as the input, then ohter applications can receive my audio through it.

Solutions I found are:

1. Stereo MIX.
2. Virtual audio cable. I can only control the virtual MIC(output) through the VAC INPUT.

These two solutions partly meets my requirement. However, What I want is to directly control the input stream of the microphone.

And I think it's possible to achieve this by providing a communication endpoint like socket or providing an  programming api to manually design the input of VMIC. If there any open source library supports these features?

I find a `WO mic` software in google, It looks like only a vitual microphone is setted, and the client software can send audio from phone into this VMIC. How does it connct with the driver, could it be possible to send my own audio through my program or script?

These are related questions in Stack and none of them suits my requirements.

- [Is there a program that allows me to send audio output to a microphone input (either real or virtual microphone)?](https://superuser.com/questions/603294/is-there-a-program-that-allows-me-to-send-audio-output-to-a-microphone-input-ei)
- [How to create a virtual audio device and stream audio input with it](https://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it)

Comment: You would be better to ask here "Software Recommendations" @ our sister site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "send my audio into the microphone as the input" This doesn't make any sense. You mean you want to send sound to a speaker then re-record it from your mic? I doubt that's what you intended, so would you like to clarify? I suspect you're looking for something that plugs to the Windows APO, like https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/ or Voicemeeter

Comment: @Tetsujin No, I mean sent to recorder. Because I wish the application that uses the mic could listen what I manually putted.